# Using id<protocol> for file's owner in Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that I am instantiating from a nib using `instantiateWithOwner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options`. When the nib is instantiated, I am saving it to an IBOutlet defined in my view controller, which is set as the file's owner in the .xib file. Everything's been working great.

I've now come across the need to use this custom cell in multiple view controllers. I was hoping that I could define a protocol (e.g. CustomCellOwner), which multiple view controllers could implement. The protocol would simply define the IBOutlet used to reference the cell when instantiated.

So ideally, I would like to set "file's owner" to:

```
id <CustomCellOwner>
```

in Interface Builder.

However, Interface Builder only seems to allow you to set file's owner to a known class, not to an id implementing a protocol?

Is there any way to do this? Or, a simpler way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Complete sidenote, can you point me to some kind of guide or sample of how you are doing this because it sounds great, currently i have to loop through a nib to find the proper view to use in my custom cells. This is not ideal. And it sounds like you have a great solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate on " it only seems to allow you to set file's owner to a known class, not to an id implementing a protocol?"  Does it mean interface builder?

Comment: @rooftop yes, "it" refers to Interface Builder in that case. When editing/configuring the file's owner object, there is a "Class" option that allows you to select the class of the file's owner. That box in IB is not allowing me to enter id<some protocol> as the type, and I'm wondering if this is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the solution you're asking for, but you could make a `UIViewController` subclass that you subclass for each view controller that needs to use your nib. Something like:

```
@interface CustomCellOwnerViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *someButton;
-(IBAction)doSomething;
@end
```

And then use that as the base class for each:

```
@interface FirstView : CustomCellOwnerViewController
```

Then you could simply set `File's Owner` to `CustomCellOwnerViewController` with no problems.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today and didn't find a good solution.  I did however hack it so that it seems to work ok.  It definitely feels like a hack though.

First I created a "fakeOwner" class like this:

```
@interface fakeOwner : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet MyBaseCell* itemTableCell;
@end

@implementation fakeOwner
@synthesize itemTableCell;
@end
```

I then set the object's owner in the XIB as fakeOwner and connected the outlet.  Then for each controller that wants to use these cells I add the same property and create the class like this:

```
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyBaseCell" owner:self options:nil];
    MyBaseCell* itemCell = self.itemTableCell;
    self.itemTableCell = nil;
```

Since the fakeOwner and my controller have the same IBOutlet, loading the cell with the controller as the owner causes the connection to happen even though that isn't what is explicitly set in the XIB.

Not 100% if the memory management is right currently (I think it's ok), but other than that it seems to work great.  I would love to see a better way of doing this though.

Answer (score 1):

Making a fake owner will work; however, such a solution may be fragile and inextensible. In a sense, the cell owns itself, but even that is technically incorrect. The truth is that `UITableViewCell`s do not have owners.

The proper way to implement a custom table view cells is to first create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. In this class you will define all of the IBOutlets and such for the cell. Here is a sample of a header file:

```
@interface RBPersonCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel * nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel * ageLabel;

- (void)setupWithPerson:(Person *)person;

@end
```

From there, I have a convenience method that creates the cell from the nib, if necessary:

```
+ (id)cellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseID fromNib:(UINib *)nib {

    if (!reuseID)
        reuseID = [self cellIdentifier];

    id cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseID];

    if (!cell) {

        NSArray * nibObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];

        // Sanity check. 
        NSAssert2(([nibObjects count] > 0) && 
                  [[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[self class]],
                  @"Nib '%@' does not appear to contain a valid %@", 
                  [self nibName], NSStringFromClass([self class]));

        cell = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This method encapsulates all of the creation code so I never have to see it or rewrite it. It assumes that the custom cell is the first root view in the nib. This is a fairly safe assumption since you should only have the custom cell as a root view.

With all this code in place, you are ready to work in Interface Builder. You first need to set the custom class in the identity inspect. Next, don't forget to set your cell identifier. For convenience, it's best to use the name of the custom class. When you drag your connections, rather than drag them to File's Owner, drag your connections to the custom cell itself.

Most of what I have learned about custom table view cells comes from [iOS Recipes](http://pragprog.com/book/cdirec/ios-recipes) recipes 15-16. Here is a [free extract](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/cdirec/table.pdf) directly from [The Pragmatic Bookshelf](http://pragprog.com/). You can check out that book for more details.

**EDIT:**

I finally got around to open sourcing my `RBSmartTableViewCell` class. You can find it on my [GitHub](https://github.com/rob-brown/RBSmartTableViewCell). You should find this class more useful than the code directly from iOS Recipes, since my class treats all cells the same, regardless of whether they are constructed using XIBs, UIStoryboard, or code. This repo also includes working samples.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5.0 there is now the `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method on `UITableView` which I believe attempts to solve a similar problem.

From the documentation:

> When you register a nib object with the table view and later call the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method, passing in the registered identifier, the table view instantiates the cell from the nib object if it is not already in the reuse queue.

This could be an alternative approach depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to create a lightweight 'factory' object that handles the creation of the cells for you. This object would be the `FilesOwner` in interface builder, with the `rootObject` outlet set appropriately.

```
@interface NibLoader : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UINib     * nib;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet id rootObject;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)bundleOrNil;
- (id)instantiateRootObject;

@end


@implementation NibLoader

@synthesize nib, rootObject;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)bundleOrNil {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:name bundle:bundleOrNil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)instantiateRootObject {
    self.rootObject = nil;
    [self.nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    NSAssert(self.rootObject != nil, @"NibLoader: Nib did not set rootObject.");
    return self.rootObject;
}

@end
```

Then in the view controllers:

```
NibLoader *customCellLoader = [[NibLoader alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
self.customCell = customCellLoader.instantiateRootObject;
```

I prefer explicitly setting the root object instead of searching through the array returned from `instantiateWithOwner:options:` because I know the position of the objects in this array has changed in the past.