# Giving a xib multiple file owners

Tags: swift, xib

I am attempting to have a header view appear on multiple viewcontroller's tableviews. I do not know what I should set the xib files owner class to. I am trying to do this so that I can call a button on the header's action. I have already tried UIViewController and have had no luck. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Create a superclass that all the relevant view controllers subclass, put the relevant actions/outlets in there and set the owner class to the superclass. Similar to objective C version here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368635/using-idprotocol-for-files-owner-in-interface-builder

Comment: I have tried making a class that is a uiviewcontroller and setting the other VC's to that class instead of their normal UIViewController and the files owner as that class as well but it still will not connect

Comment: You should post your non-working code and explain how you're trying to connect it - this will make it easier for someone to help you

Comment: the thing is that I really don't think theres much necessary code because literally all I need to know is how to give a xib multiple file owners so that I can connect it and code.

Comment: If you're trying what I suggested and it's not working, please show your code. If you're waiting for someone to write the code for you, you *might* be lucky but generally speaking on Stack Overflow you'll get a much better response if you show what you've tried and explain why it's not achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best (in my opinion) if you create a dedicated controller class for the view. You can load and add the loaded ViewController like:

```
let cmVC = ColorMenuVC(nibName: "ColorMenu", bundle: Bundle.main, textProperty: _textProperty!)

    //font menu initialization & settings
    cmVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

    //popover settings
    let popover = cmVC.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.delegate = self
    popover?.barButtonItem = sender
    popover?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.any

    //presenting
    present(cmVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This example for Popovers, but I hope this will helpful. The ColorMenuVC is extending the UIViewController, but here is the original class how to init:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname